# how to call logic of batch class in another apex class and send an email

Tags: apex

```
global class BatchApexDefaultEmail implements database.Batchable<sObject>{
    global database.QueryLocator start(database.BatchableContext bc){
        return database.getQueryLocator([select id,name,(select id,LastName from contacts) from account]);
    }
    global void execute(database.BatchableContext bc,List<Account>scope){
        List<contact>conList = new List<Contact>();           
            for(Account acc : scope){         
            If(acc.contacts.size()>3){
                for(Contact c: acc.contacts){
                  contact con = new contact();
                    con.Id = c.Id;
                    con.Email ='smrafi1437@gmail.com';    
                    conList.add(con);                    
                }
                                    
            }
        }
                  
        if(conList.size()>0){
        update conList;        
        }   
}
    global void finish(database.BatchableContext bc){
```

here, i want send mail above logic using apex class

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new apex class BatchApexDefaultEmail_Processor and call it from execute method, then send an email from there using SingleEmailMessage.
Update your batch class as below:

```
global void execute(database.BatchableContext bc,List<Account> scope){
    BatchApexDefaultEmail_Processor processor = new BatchApexDefaultEmail_Processor();
    processor.sendEmail(scope);
}
```

Adding the code of processor class below:

```
public class BatchApexDefaultEmail_Processor{
    public void procesAccount(List<Account> scope){
        for(Account acc : scope){         
            If(acc.contacts.size()>3){
                for(Contact c: acc.contacts){
                  contact con = new contact();
                    con.Id = c.Id;
                    con.Email ='smrafi1437@gmail.com';    
                    conList.add(con);                    
                }
                                    
            }
        }
                  
        if(conList.size()>0){
            update conList;        
        }   
        sendEmail();
    }

    public void sendEmail(){
        public void sendMail(){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        string[] to = new string[] {'smrafi1437@gmail.com'};
        string[] cc = new string[] {'smrafi1437@gmail.com'};
        
        email.setToAddresses(to);
        if(ccMail!=null && ccMail != '')
            email.setCcAddresses(cc);
        if(repmail!=null && repmail!= '')
            email.setInReplyTo(repMail);
        
        email.setSubject('Test Mail');
        
        email.setHtmlBody('Hello, <br/><br/>This is the test mail that you generated. <br/>The Email Id for which this mail was generated by '+toMail+'<br/><br/>Regards<br/> Developer');
        try{
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });
        }catch(exception e){
            apexpages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.error,e.getMessage()));
        }
        
        toMail = '';
        ccMail = '';
        repMail = '';
    }      
    }
}
```